# How to add Google Analytics to Plone template

Tags: google-analytics, plone

I want to add event tracking to an outbound url that connects users to our knowledge base. The knowledge base tool is assigned to a viewlet and contains simple .js and .pt files. I haven't found much info about adding event tracking to Plone, aside from collective.googleanalytics, which we are not using at this time. So I'm wondering how to add the tracking code.

The section from the .pt file that contains the url is:

```
    <div id="askthelion"
       tal:define="intelliresponse string:${here/portal_url}/intelliresponseProcess;">

        <form id="asklion" action="http://psu.intelliresponse.com/studentaid/index.jsp"
```

Would this work?

```
    <form id="asklion" action="http://psu.intelliresponse.com/studentaid/index.jsp" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','IR','onClick','AsktheLion']);"
```

Comment: It might. It's possible that the _gaq.push method won't be able to send the ajax tracking request before the page click is handled though. This isn't really a plone question but more of a google analytics question.

Comment: ok. I didn't look up adding events to forms. Thanks for the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick must be in the form button, for example:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','IR','onClick','AsktheLion']);" >
```

Then you can use Firebug "Net" tab to see if the browser is sending the request to GA when you click the button. You should see something like "GET __utm.gif" as a new request just after the button press.

Comment: ah, ok. I will give that a try.